# Arithmetic mean, Geometric mean, Harmonic mean in trapezoid

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

How do I find the Arithmetic mean, the Geometric mean and the Harmonic mean of the two basis of a random trapezoid?

Comment: Elaborate your question. What two??

Comment: have a look here: http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/EMAT6680.2000/Umberger/EMAT6690smu/Essay3smu/Essay3smu.html

Comment: That was fast! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you draw a parallel through of diagonal intersection to base, you get segment which is **harmonic mean**.

If you draw a parallel to base so that area of upper trapezoid and lower trapezoir is in ratio of upper and lower base, you get segment which is **geometric mean**.